# How can I get my nested class inside a templated class to accept other versions of itself?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The following doesn't compile, how can I do this? I think the example shows my intent, but I'll try to add a blurb if people are confused.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
private:
    struct B
    {
        template<typename T2> 
        B& operator=( const A<T2>::B& right ){} //  how can I make this work?
    };

    template<typename T2> friend class A;
    template<typename T2> friend class A<T2>::B;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental idea of your assignment operator is flawed, as even with the addition of a `typename`, it's a *non-deducible context*. As such, the template parameter will never be deduced and the assignment operator will never work unless you explicitly specify a type like `B.operator=<some_type>(other_B)`.

An easier version would be to just make it a normal function template, and SFINAE your way out.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class> struct is_a_B;

template<class B2>
typename std::enable_if<
  is_a_B<B2>::value,
  B&
>::type operator=(B2 const& other){
  // ...
}
```

Now all that's left is the `is_a_B` type trait. You can make this easy on yourself with possible false positives:

```
template<class B>
struct is_a_B{
  typedef char yes;
  typedef yes (&no)[2];

  template<class T>
  static yes test(typename T::I_am_a_B_type*);
  template<class T>
  static no  test(...);

  static bool const value = sizeof(test<B>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Just provide the `I_am_a_B_type` typedef in your `B` class.

[Live example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/MYMiH). Comment out the `b1 = 5;` line and it compiles as [seen here](http://ideone.com/amRkx).

---

And now for the <strike>slightly more</strike> <strike>perverted</strike> complicated way with no false-positives. :)

```
template<bool Cond, class OnTrue>
struct and_v{
  static bool const value = OnTrue::value;
};

template<class OnTrue>
struct and_v<false, OnTrue>{
  static bool const value = false;
};

template<class B>
struct is_a_B{
  typedef char yes;
  typedef yes (&no)[2];

  template<class T>
  static yes has_parent(typename T::parent*);
  template<class T>
  static no  has_parent(...);

  template<class T>
  static yes is_A(A<T>*);
  static no  is_A(...);

  template<class T>
  struct lazy_test{
    typedef typename std::add_pointer<typename T::parent>::type p_type;
    static bool const value = sizeof(is_A(p_type(0))) == sizeof(yes);
  };

  static bool const value = and_v<sizeof(has_parent<B>(0)) == sizeof(yes),
                                  lazy_test<B>>::value;
};
```

For this one you need a `typedef A<T> parent;` inside `B`. It's staged in two parts:

- First I test if a `parent` typedef exists, and if it does
- If it's actually a typedef of the `A` class template.

Sadly, the logical operators (`&&`, `||`, `?:`) don't short-circuit in template code like I hoped, so I had to write those `and_v` templates + a lazy tester that only gets evaluated if a `parent` typedef exists.

[Live example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/tyVTo). Again, comment out the `b1 = 5;` line to make it compile as [seen here](http://ideone.com/szZsc).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I ended up just moving `B` outside of `A` and 'hiding' it in a namespace that starts with `_` to indicate that users shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @Dave : Names starting with `_` are reserved for the implementation. Boost's precedent is to use a namespace called `detail`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Depending on the following characters, maybe only in the global namespace. ;)

Comment: True, but it's easier to make a blanket statement to discourage use of prefixed underscores altogether. Comments are non-normative after all. :-P

Comment: +1 nice template approach, but a quick question as well:  In your `lazy_test` struct, if the type `T` is not a `B`-type, and therefore doesn't contain a `typedef A<T> parent`, how would `typedef typename std::add_pointer<typename T::parent>::type p_type;` still instantiate so that `lazy_test<>::value` can have a true or false value? In other words, if `T::parent` doesn't exist, wouldn't that start throwing compiler errors before a true or false value could be generated?  Was this put in to avoid the "false positives" where `T::parent` was defined, but wasn't a type `A<T>`?

Comment: @Jason: The answer explains this, directly below the code. I *first* check if that typedef exists, and *only if it does*, do I evaluate `lazy_test<T>::value`. The great thing about members of a class template is that they're not defined until you actually *use* them, which I do not do if there is no `parent` typedef. And yes, that was to work around false-positives. Note that I could also have just used `::parent` directly and let that trigger the compiler error, but a "no assignment operator found" error is nicer than "no type named 'parent' found", don't you think? :)

Comment: Okay, I see what's going on now, the passing of a `lazy_test<>` type as a template argument doesn't instantiate anything in the template until you attempt to instantiate `lazy_test<>::value` ... So you can have a `and_v<false, lazy_test<B>>` and not get a compiler error. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should not work at all.
Here is the reason

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    private:
    struct B
    {
        template<typename T2> 
        B& operator=( const typename A<T2>::B& right ){}
    };

    template<typename T2> friend class A;
    template<typename T2> friend class A<T2>::B;
};

template <>
class A<int>
{
};
```

As you can see there is not **A< int >::B** class at all!